# Leg Training with Patella alta

Tags: weightlifting, legs, knees, knee-pain

A few days ago I visited my doctor because I got pain right besides and under my kneecap in the right leg when walking and going up/down stairs (only when extending my leg and only sometimes, it's pretty weird). However, after examining me he could not find anything that might cause the pain and speculated it has something to do with my training.

**My current leg exercises:**
leg press (would love to do squats, but there is no squat rack in my current gym), machine leg extensions, machine leg curls, romanian deadlifts, standing calf raises. - after my knee started to hurt about 3 weeks ago I stopped doing leg extensions and curls because I read about them being really bad for your knees. The pain got less, but still remains to this day.

**My planned new leg exercises:**
leg press, split squats/lunges, gliding leg curls, romanian deadlifts, standing calf raises

Since I have Patella alta (maybe genetically or something, I never had an patellar tendon rupture), are there any particular exercises I should strictly avoid? I also asked my doctor that question but he couldn't answer it cause he's just a general physician. The local orthopedist has waiting times of around 1-2 months, so I'm seeking some advice until I got my appointment there in November.

**Are the new leg exercises I planned to implement into my workout routine suitable for my condition?** If not, what exercises do I need to avoid and why?